# Problem setting image info when creating an article via the J4 REST API

Tags: joomla-4.x, development, joomla-api

I’ve been using the J4 REST API for a while to create articles from form data through the Webhook feature of the **Convert Forms** extension.  It works great for both standard article fields and for custom fields.

Now I’m attempting to set an Intro Image for these articles, and I have not been able to get it to work.

I have not been able to get this to work using Postman either.  I tried passing JSON with the key “images” as part of the body JSON for a POST:

```
{
    "alias": "my-article3",
    "articletext": "My text",
    "catid": 54,
    "language": "*",
    "metadesc": "",
    "metakey": "",
    "images": { "image_intro": "https://www.zzz.org/images/portraits/staff/Jeff.jpeg", "image_intro_alt": "Jeff portrait"},
    "title": "Here's an article"
}
```

But that doesn’t work either.  The article gets created, but no image settings come through.

Do you have any suggestions for how to make this work?  I have not been able to find a working example anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried adding an image without the `"image_intro_alt": "Jeff portrait"` portion?

Comment: Good thought.  Just tried it, but no go.